# .done is not supported in ajax callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have added `.done` to my *ajax* callback and now getting

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

in *myPage.aspx*:

```
function myFunction(albumNb) {

        alert("START myFunction");
        var aNb = albumNb.toString();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'myPage.aspx/TestFunction',
            type: "POST",                
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'name':'" + aNb + "'}",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (result) { alert("done !"); }); 


    }
```

What is wrong with my code?
I try to use `.done` to wait for `TestFunction()` in code-behind to complete and return `result`.

I need to process that `result`.
Thank you

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The [jQuery `deferred.done()` function](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) for AJAX calls was added somewhat recently (v1.5 I believe), verify what version of jQuery you're using (e.g. `$.fn.jquery; // => '1.x'`).

Comment: Also, your `data` parameter is wrong. Just use `data: { name: aNb }`. Let jQuery do the JSON serialization, it will do a better job.

Comment: @Meagar jQuery doesn't do json serialization... Changing to that format results in jQuery sending POST name/value pairs to the server rather than the expected JSON. doing so would actually make his ajax request fail. If the data option contains a string, jQuery won't touch it and will instead send it as is.

Comment: Which line is giving you that error?

Comment: In the master page that myPage uses there is:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
I have tried to include 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Still getting an error.

Comment: exception points to the whole $.ajax statement. Error occurred after I've added .done. If I remove .done all works again.

Comment: @KarenSlon the sources you have shown in your comment point to `jquery-ui` not `jquery` are you sure the you included `jquery` itself?

Comment: var jq = jQuery.fn.jquery; alert(jq);  used in myFunction() tells me that "version is 1.3.2", even after I include <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  AND all other versions mentioned previously

Comment: for versin 1.5.1 it's  jquery/1.5.1 and same for 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend

```
$.post('myPage.aspx/TestFunction',
  { name : albumNb.toString() })
.done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I prefer to do ajax json requests, in your case it would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'name=' + aNb,
    beforeSend: function (x) {
        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType('application/json; charset=utf-8');
        }
    },
    url: 'myPage.aspx/TestFunction',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: `'name=' + aNb` isn't JSON.

Comment: You should prefer using `.done`, assuming your version of jQuery supports it. The only reason to not choose promises is because you don't yet understand them; they are objectively *better* than passing around success callbacks.

Comment: Liam, following does not work at all for some reason:
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "json", data: "{'name':'" + aNb + "'}", beforeSend: function (x) {
                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) 
                             {x.overrideMimeType('application/json; charset=utf-8');}
                    },                    
                    url: 'myPage.aspx/TestMethod',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });