# Which jQuery version introduced .done fro $.ajax calls?

Tags: jquery

Which jQuery version introduced `.done` for `$.ajax` calls?

I need to use `.done` in `$.ajax` call, but latest version 1.10.1 does not seem to include `.done`.

Thank you

Comment: how are you trying to use it?

Comment: You should have checked the Docs right?  From http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/, seems to be 1.5 and it still supported in latest version.

Comment: Show us your ajax call - there must be an error somewhere

Comment: you are most likely including jQuery more than once, whether it's intentionally or not.

Comment: Karen, you should definitively work on your acceptance ratio (7 months, no accepted answers). Also, avoid posting the same issue multiple times. Users already told you to replace your jQuery library with a more recent version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707241/why-latest-version-of-jquery-is-not-seeing-used-by-my-code) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705411/done-is-not-supported-in-ajax-callback). If you are getting the same advice multiple times - from different users - with working examples this is a good indication that you should try their suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Its added in `version: 1.5`, See the [deferred.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) docs and it is still supported

Answer (score 0):

[jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object (and the `.done` method) was introduced in jQuery 1.5. Quoting the official documentation:

> **Deprecation Notice:** The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and
>   `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`,
>   and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

`.done()` was neither removed or deprecated, it works as expected in jQuery 1.10.1.

---

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/Pdgvc/)

Comment: var jq = $.fn.jquery;  alert(jq); in my function returns "1.3.2", looks like JQuery version used is 1.3.2 ? I do have in master page <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>. So, why $.fn.jquery  reports version 1.3.2 ? Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Since you are using Google CDN, just update your library to the latest versions: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. Also, make sure that you are not loading two or more versions of jQuery in the same page.

Comment: versions 1.4.2 and 1.8.5 specified in master page written before I started to work with it. Removal of one of those generates errors, but still does not allow to use .done. and $.fn.jquery reports version 1.3.2 right before $.ajax call.

Comment: Like I said in the answer versions <= to 1.5 will not work. Just follow the link in the comment above and replace your current versions by `1.10.2/jquery.min.js` and `1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js`. Plus make sure that version 1.3.2 is not being loaded from some other place.